# Powershell: Replace string in File1 based on string in File2

Tags: string, powershell, file, replace

I am being forced to use Powershell because of my work.  I have used it to do a couple of things but one of my codes is now trash because I have to update a string in a file to include a year that is in a second file.  Here is what I'm working with:

File1: Contains a few strings but in there is 48 strings that say:
`Jenga_Sequence-XXXX.consensus_Bob_0.6_quality_20`

The main point of the string is `Sequence-XXXX`, sorry for the random place holders.

File2: is a table that has the strings:
`John/USA/Sequence-XXXX/Year`

I need to replace the strings in File1 with the corresponding Strings in File2.

Sample Text of File1:

```
Jenga_Sequence-0001.consensus_Bob_0.6_quality_20
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
Jenga_Sequence-0002.consensus_Bob_0.6_quality_20
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
Jenga_Sequence-0003.consensus_Bob_0.6_quality_20
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
Jenga_Sequence-0004.consensus_Bob_0.6_quality_20
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
Jenga_Sequence-0005.consensus_Bob_0.6_quality_20
QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ
```

Sample Table of File2:

```
|Sequence_ID|Date|
|---------------------------|----------|
|John/USA/Sequence-0003/2020|10/11/2020|
|John/USA/Sequence-0001/2021|1/5/2021|
|John/USA/Sequence-0005/2021|1/10/2021|
|John/USA/Sequence-0004/2020|12/23/2020|
|John/USA/Sequence-0002/2021|1/6/2021|
```

So, I need a Powershell code that replaces
`Jenga_Sequence-0001.consensus_Bob_0.6_quality_20` with `John/USA/Sequence-0001/2021`,
`Jenga_Sequence-0002.consensus_Bob_0.6_quality_20` with `John/USA/Sequence-0002/2021`,
`Jenga_Sequence-0003.consensus_Bob_0.6_quality_20` with `John/USA/Sequence-0003/2020`, and so on.  There are typically 48 of these in a file.

My previous code simple replaced "Jenga_" with "John/USA/" and ".consensus_Bob_0.6_quality_20" with "/2020" but now that we are seeing "/2021" the static code will not work.

I am still open to replacing pieces of the string and having a code that sets the year replacement to the correct year.

That was the angle I was doing a broad search on but I could never find anything specific enough to help.

Any help will be appreciated!

EDIT: Here is the part of my previous code that dealt with the finding and replacing, even though I feel it needs to be trashed:

```
$filePath = 'Jenga_Combined.txt'
$tempFilePath = "$env:TEMP\$($filePath | Split-Path -Leaf)"
$find = 'Jenga_'
$replace = 'John/USA/'
$find2 = '.consensus_Bob_0.6_quality_20'
$replace2 = '/2020'

(Get-Content -Path $filePath) -replace $find, $replace -replace $find2, $replace2 | Add-Content -Path $tempFilePath

Remove-Item -Path $filePath
Move-Item -Path $tempFilePath -Destination $filePath
```

EDIT2: The "Real Data" from file2.  File2 is a Tab Delimited .txt file which makes it not "look great" when copy and pasting.  Hopefully this helps.  File1 is exactly like above (although the AAAAA stuff is roughly 30,000 letters long)

> Sequence_ID   date
> John/USA/Sequence-0003/2020   2020-10-11
> John/USA/Sequence-0001/2021   2021-01-05
> John/USA/Sequence-0005/2021   2021-01-10
> John/USA/Sequence-0004/2020   2020-12-23
> John/USA/Sequence-0002/2021   2021-01-06

Dan

Comment: "My previous code" - what previous code? Please include the code you're hoping to update/modify in your post

Comment: Mathias R. Jessen, please see the EDIT I have added to the post.  I fully believe that this old code trash now that I have to deal with this year issue, as it only replaced parts of the original string without any coding for that to be different depending on other variables.

Comment: Please edit again and show us the **real content** of File2. It looks like a CSV file, but now we cannot be sure of that.

Comment: Theo, See EDIT2 above.  File2 is a Tab Delimited .txt file that doesn't copy and paste visually well, which is why I did not have it in before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The common factor here is the Sequence_ID number in both files.
You can do this like:

```
$csvData = Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\File2.txt' -Delimiter "`t"

$result = switch -Regex -File 'D:\Test\Jenga_Combined.txt' {
    '^Jenga_Sequence-(\d+).*' {
        $replace = $csvData | Where-Object { $_.Sequence_ID -like "*Sequence-$($matches[1])*" }
        if (!$replace) { Write-Warning "No corresponding Sequence_ID $($matches[1]) found!"; $_ }
        else { $replace.Sequence_ID }
    }
    default { $_ }
}

# output on screen
$result

# output to new file
$result | Set-Content -Path 'D:\Test\Jenga_Combined_NEW.txt' -Force
```

Output on screen:

```
John/USA/Sequence-0001/2021
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
John/USA/Sequence-0002/2021
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
John/USA/Sequence-0003/2020
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
John/USA/Sequence-0004/2020
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
John/USA/Sequence-0005/2021
QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ
```

Of course, you need to change the file paths to match your environment

Comment: Well...that's frustrating.  I integrated it where it needed it to test and it worked great.  So then I fully integrated it and it stopped working.  I then went back to my test folder and it no longer works.  I have started again from the top, redoing everything and again, it doesn't work.  I am now at a complete loss....  I am getting the output file but it is not changing the sequence names.  It is, in essence, just duplicating file1.

Comment: @DanBonser That means the strings in the file are not like your example. Perhaps you could show me a few lines **exactly** as they are. Did you check the if you have put in the file paths correctly?

Comment: I have worked around it by forcing a change outside of the code.  I also realized that there was a Caret (>) in front of the Jenga's in my example and the HTML coding was screwing up what was shown.  The short thing is, I have now made it work.  Thanks a TON for this help!